# How to construct a relative price index

Tags: regression, data-transformation

I have prices of different food items for three time periods (2011, 2015 and 2018) at the household level. So I have a panel with 3 time periods and around 5000 households. I want to see the impact of food item prices on their consumption by running a regression. I have deflated the price data using the CPI. As I am working with price data for the first time I have the following question.
Instead of including the own price of a food item in my regression, I want to construct a 'price index' using the own price of a food item as well as substitutes. However, I am not sure how to construct such an index.
Any suggestion would be welcome.